# How to change images for time ?? python, using tk

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried the tutorial below that site.

https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-stopwatch/

I want to add codes can changing the image when after +1 hour.

but I don't know proper space this code

```py
penguin = ['u', 'g', 'n', 'e', 'P'] # filename
hour = 0
```

```py
def changePenguin():
    pho = PhotoImage(file=penguin[hour]+'.png').subsample(15)
    img = Label(ws, image = pho)
    img.pack()
    img.place(x=130, y=50)
```

Comment: Also you have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16424091/11106801) problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very simple to do. Tkinter has a built-in `after` method that allows you to specify the amount of milliseconds you want to wait before calling a function or method.

You have to store a persistent reference to images or they will not display.

To avoid using/juggling `globals` the below example stores the label on the root, and the persistent image reference on the  label. This makes it very simple to reference these things for creation and destruction.

```
import tkinter as tk

def change_image(index:int, secs:int, subsamp:int=1) -> None:
    #destroy current image label and persistent image reference
    if getattr(root, 'imglbl', None):
        root.imglbl.destroy()

    #create new image label
    root.imglbl = tk.Label(root)
    root.imglbl.pack()
    
    #create a persistent reference and assign image to label
    root.imglbl.img = tk.PhotoImage(file=f'{img_names[index]}.png').subsample(subsamp)
    root.imglbl['image'] = root.imglbl.img

    #next index, wrap overflow
    index = (index + 1) % len(img_names)

    #schedule next call
    root.after(secs*1000, change_image, index, secs, subsamp)

#init root
root = tk.Tk()

#basename for all images
img_names = ('img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4')

#init first image and scheduling of the next image
change_image(0, 3600, 15)

#app main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Your example calls `pack` then `place`. Choose one, using both on one widget simultaneously is impossible.